# JavaScript: Convert array of objects into array of object of array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

JavaScript: Convert array of objects into array of object of array of objects

Convert: Input

[{date: 2021, name: 'New York', price: 452}, {date: 2020, name: 'New York', price: 452}, {date: 2021, name: 'Oregon', price: 452} , .... ]

The output required is:

```
        {
           name: "New York",
           values: [
             {date: "2000", price: "50"},
             {date: "2001", price: "10"},
             {date: "2002", price: "5"},
             {date: "2003", price: "71"},
             {date: "2004", price: "20"},
             {date: "2005", price: "9"},
             {date: "2006", price: "220"},
             {date: "2007", price: "235"},
             {date: "2008", price: "61"},
             {date: "2009", price: "10"}
           ]
         },
         
         {
           name: "Oregon",
           values: [
             {date: "2000", price: "20"},
             {date: "2001", price: "10"},
             {date: "2002", price: "5"},
             {date: "2003", price: "71"},
             {date: "2004", price: "20"},
             {date: "2005", price: "9"},
             {date: "2006", price: "220"},
             {date: "2007", price: "235"},
             {date: "2008", price: "61"},
             {date: "2009", price: "10"}
           ]
         }
       ];
```

Comment: You should put your own research efforts into solving your problem, show what you have tried, and add the actual code that you have written plus the precise problem that you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```js
const data = [{date: 2021,name: 'New York',price: 452}, {date: 2020,name: 'New York',price: 452}, {date: 2021,name: 'Oregon',price: 452}]

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((res, {name,...rest}) => {
  return {
    ...res,
    [name]: {
      name,
      values: [...(res[name] || {values: []}).values, rest]
    }
  }
}, []))

console.log(result)
```